# How to find sum of even numbers in a list using recursion in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++builder

```
int list::Sum_Even_Values(node *head)
{

     static int sum=0; 
      if(!isempty())
            {
            if(head->info %2==0)
            return head->info +Sum_Even_Values(head->next);
            }
}
```

Comment: What happens if `isempty()` returns true? Or if `head->info % 2 != 0`? What do you return then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to achieve the same thing by passing the `sum` variable by reference at every call to the function.

```
void sumEvenValues(Node * head, int& sum){
    if (head != NULL){
        if (head->info % 2 == 0){
            sum += head->info;
        }
        sumEvenValues(head->next, sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing a function that returns a value, recursive or not, you need to explore all paths through the code, not only your main "path of interest."

In your specific case you need to decide what to return

- **When the current node represents an even number** - your code already covers this case,
- **When the current node represents an odd number** - you need to return the same value as if the node is not there, and
- **When there is no current node** - that's the value you'd return when the list is null or empty (i.e. zero).

You need to add `return` statements for the remaining two cases. Once you do that, your function would be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `static` variable, as you won't be able to reset it back to 0 if you need to sum the list multiple times.  Try this instead:

```
int list::Sum_Even_Values(node *head)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if (head) {
        if ((head->info % 2) == 0)
            sum = head->info;
        sum += Sum_Even_Values(head->next);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/IK1Rkw)